# Does the syntax of machine language differ from machine to anther?

Tags: machine-code

I have a question about Machine Languages. 
If i write a program the prints "Hello World", using machine language, will my syntax be different depending on the machine I am writing my code on.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that by "machine code" you mean human readable assembly language code and not binary CPU instruction code.

I would say that machine languages do not have a syntax, that is what separates low level languages from high level languages.  Or, to the extent that machine languages have syntax, the syntax is all the same.

Compiling a high-level language program requires a parser to determine what items are variables, control structures, and function definitions.  But, machine languages have no such constructs (except for control structures) so there is no thing that we think of as a syntax.

In a machine language, every line you write instructs that machine (or CPU) to perform a task.  Tasks can be storing information, retrieving information, comparing values, or other things.

If you are writing a "Hello, World" program for an x86 machine and a SH4 machine, the code will be different.  The code will be more different than if you wrote the "Hello, World" program in C or Python.  But the "syntax" of the program - the particular layout or format of your machine code and the ability to read your machine code - will be the same for both x86 and SH4 machine code.